# How to determine latest stable version of node from nvm?

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

I ran `nvm ls-remote` and the end of the list looked like this:

```
       v14.17.6   (LTS: Fermium)
       v14.18.0   (LTS: Fermium)
       v14.18.1   (LTS: Fermium)
       v14.18.2   (LTS: Fermium)
       v14.18.3   (LTS: Fermium)
       v14.19.0   (LTS: Fermium)
       v14.19.1   (Latest LTS: Fermium)
        v15.0.0
        v15.0.1
        v15.1.0
        ...
       v16.11.1
       v16.12.0
       v16.13.0   (LTS: Gallium)
       v16.13.1   (LTS: Gallium)
       v16.13.2   (LTS: Gallium)
       v16.14.0   (LTS: Gallium)
       v16.14.1   (LTS: Gallium)
       v16.14.2   (Latest LTS: Gallium)
        v17.0.0
        v17.0.1
        v17.1.0
        ...
        v17.8.0
        v17.9.0
```

My goal is to get the most recent version that's stable (ie. recommended). How do I determine that from this list?

Comment: nvm install node will show you and install the lastest stable version. I don't recall a specific command for this.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, even major versions (14.x.x, 16.x.x) are recommended for general use. Odd major versions (15.x.x, 17.x.x) are considered development versions.

Comment: @0xRyN `nvm install node` will install the latest version of node, ie from this list it will install `v17.9.0`  which is not recommended for general usage. Better is to use `nvm install --lts` which will install the latest LTS version (in this case 16.14.2)

Comment: Of possible relevance: [How do I check the release status of nodejs versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71518977/how-do-i-programmatically-check-the-release-status-of-the-installed-node-js-vers/71520193#71520193)

Answer (score 8):

###### Show current installed version

`nvm current` shows you the current version you have installed.

```
C:\>nvm current
v18.13.0
```

###### Show all available versions

`nvm list available` shows you a partial list of all available versions there are.

```
C:\>nvm list available

|   CURRENT    |     LTS      |  OLD STABLE  | OLD UNSTABLE |
|--------------|--------------|--------------|--------------|
|    19.5.0    |   18.13.0    |   0.12.18    |   0.11.16    |
|    19.4.0    |   18.12.1    |   0.12.17    |   0.11.15    |
|    19.3.0    |   18.12.0    |   0.12.16    |   0.11.14    |
|    19.2.0    |   16.19.0    |   0.12.15    |   0.11.13    |
|    19.1.0    |   16.18.1    |   0.12.14    |   0.11.12    |
|    19.0.1    |   16.18.0    |   0.12.13    |   0.11.11    |
|    19.0.0    |   16.17.1    |   0.12.12    |   0.11.10    |
|   18.11.0    |   16.17.0    |   0.12.11    |    0.11.9    |
|   18.10.0    |   16.16.0    |   0.12.10    |    0.11.8    |
|    18.9.1    |   16.15.1    |    0.12.9    |    0.11.7    |
|    18.9.0    |   16.15.0    |    0.12.8    |    0.11.6    |
|    18.8.0    |   16.14.2    |    0.12.7    |    0.11.5    |
|    18.7.0    |   16.14.1    |    0.12.6    |    0.11.4    |
|    18.6.0    |   16.14.0    |    0.12.5    |    0.11.3    |
|    18.5.0    |   16.13.2    |    0.12.4    |    0.11.2    |
|    18.4.0    |   16.13.1    |    0.12.3    |    0.11.1    |
|    18.3.0    |   16.13.0    |    0.12.2    |    0.11.0    |
|    18.2.0    |   14.21.2    |    0.12.1    |    0.9.12    |
|    18.1.0    |   14.21.1    |    0.12.0    |    0.9.11    |
|    18.0.0    |   14.21.0    |   0.10.48    |    0.9.10    |

This is a partial list. For a complete list, visit https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases
```

###### Stable vs. experimental versions

Versions with even numbers such as `18.x` are stable.

Versions with odd numbers such as `19.x` are unstable/experimental.

See https://nodejs.org/en/

[image]

###### Install latest LTS version

LTS (Long Term Support) is the stable version.

`nvm install lts` installs the latest LTS version.

###### Select installed version

If you had, say, 17.x installed, you now also have, say, 18.x installed.

Now, you need to select the newly installed version with `nvm use 18.13.0`.

Comment: `nvm install --lts` to be precise

Comment: @GrimReaper007: I just tried `nvm install lts` and it worked without the `--` and with `--lts` it said `Unrecognized version: "--lts"`

Comment: It might work because of different OS, but according to the official [documentation](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#long-term-support) it should be `nvm install --lts` or `nvm install 'lts/*'` Please check.

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04, `nvm install lts` does not work, but `nvm install --lts` worked.

Answer (score 0):

`nvm install --lts` installs the latest LTS version.

Then, `nvm use lts/*` switches to the latest LTS version.